# Can't find out why MQTT python app isn't subscribing or receiving messages

Tags: python, flask, mqtt, paho

MQTT and flask app isn't receiving messages I'm not sure if it just isn't getting subscribed to, or if the message isn't being received by my device. Publishing messages worked I've tested it, but receiving them doesn't. Is there something I am doing wrong here.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print((message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

broker = "broker.hivemq.com"
client = mqtt.Client("mypc")
client.on_message=on_message 
client.connect(broker)
client.loop_start() 
client.subscribe('class/ledToggle')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/led/<state>')
def led(state):
    if (state == "on"):
        client.publish('class/ledToggle','1')
    elif (state == "off"):
        client.publish('class/ledToggle','0')
    time.sleep(5)
    return render_template('led.html', title = 'Led')

client.loop_stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You’re stopping the client loop - that will stop subscription/receiving  working.

Comment: That doesnt fix anything i tried changing it.

Comment: Try replacing that line with `client.loop_forever()` - if subscription then works, But doesn’t work if you delete that line completely, maybe you should look at e.g. Flask-MQTT rather than trying to roll your own solution?

Comment: `loop_forever()` won't work as it will block and `app.run()` also blocks so you can't run both on the same thread.

Comment: Yes, was trying to get OP to check they have workable MQTT setup.

Answer (score 0):

It case Flask-MQTT extension you can use decorators

If you want to subscribe to a topic right from the start make sure to wait with the subscription until the client is connected to the broker. Use the `flask_mqtt.Mqtt.on_connect()` decorator for this.

```py
@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    mqtt.subscribe('home/mytopic')
```